# How to suppress PIN Error Dialog from Keystore.load when Keystore is a USB cryptotoken

Tags: java, security, usb, pkcs#11

Hi I am using SUN `PKCS11` implementation to perform operations with PKI certificates in USB cryptotokens

I created a provider object for the particular USB token and then call

```
Keystore ks =  KeyStore.getInstance(PKCS11_KEYSTORE_TYPE,prov);
```

Then I load it with

```
keyStore.load(null, PIN.toCharArray())
```

PIN is the user entered PIN for the particular certificate

Now different cryptotokens behave differently when the load fails because of a Wrong PIN. `Keystore::load` throws an IOException when PIN is wrong however,

### For eg.

1. Watchdata USB token first throws a dialog box with a message "PIN is
   wrong. X attempts left" & then throws the IOException.
2. Gemalto & Fietian don't throw a dialog box but only throw an
   IOException

I want to show an PIN error message for all USB types, but if I add my own dialog, then on WatchData I end up getting 2 dialogs `(1 from Watchdata & 1 of my own).`

Is there a way to figure out whether the error message has already been shown? Or alternately is there a way to suppress the error dialog on dongles which show their own?

Comment: Hello @user93353. Are you using vendors PKCS#11 modules(like Watchdata’s libwdpkcs_icp.so) or opensc-pkcs11.so?

Comment: @SebB - using vendor PKCS#.

Comment: In the *WatchKey Token Tool** installation log, i see interesting modules:
`WDPKCS.dll, WDICP_P11_CCID_v34.dll,...`. Which one are you loading?

Comment: Try to use `WDICP_P11_CCID_v34.dll`instead. In `WDPKCS.dll` export-table i see the typical PKCS#11 functions + some Watchdata's functions (WD***)

Comment: This file could also be interesting when using `WDPKCS.dll`: `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WatchData\Watchdata ICP CSP v1.0\WatchSafe.ini`. I see `RetryTimes=4,MinPinLen=5,P11Message=1,...`.

Answer (score 2):

The behavior is token-specific because the standard doesn't specify, how exactly the drivers must behave. So showing the window is beyond your control. The best you can do is contact the vendor of the specific device and ask them for assistance.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

Watchdata seems to have 2 PKCS#11 modules:

- `WDICP_P11_CCID_v34.dll`: Vanilla PKCS#11 impl
- `WDPKCS.dll`: PKCS#11 + custom functions (ICP CSP v1.0).
   And here is
  what, obviously seems to be the configuation file:
  `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WatchData\Watchdata ICP CSP v1.0\WatchSafe.ini`

Possible solution to avoid the "PIN Error Dialog": *switch from* `WDPKCS.dll` *to* `WDICP_P11_CCID_v34.dll`

References:
[ProxKey User Manual](http://cryptoplanet.in/ProxKey%20User%20Manual.pdf)
and
[WatchKey USB Token Tools](http://www.watchdata.com/brazil/watchkey/index.htm)

---

The error dialog you want to suppress, how does it look like? Native? or Java/Swing-like? 
There are many "layers" involved in the process.

1. **Layers**
   Let's break the process in 4 layers:
   `1-PKCS#11(native); 2-Wrappers[IAIK, SUN, Vendors]; 3-Providers[IAIK, SUN]; 4-JCA/JCE`
   So your "error-dialog" is coming from one of these layers.
   From Layer-1: you have less control and you can just contact the vendors, just like @Eugene wrote. 
   From Layer-2 to Layer-4, your control increases, so you might do something about it, if you implement the right callbacks.
2. **Providers and wrappers** 
   [Sun:](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/p11guide.html)
   -[sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/pkcs11/SunPKCS11.java.html)
   -[sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper](http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/sun/security/pkcs11/wrapper/PKCS11.html)
   [IAIK:](https://jce.iaik.tugraz.at/sic/Products/Core_Crypto_Toolkits/PKCS_11_Provider)
   -[iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.provider](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_provider/current/index.html)
   -[iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.wrapper](http://javadoc.iaik.tugraz.at/pkcs11_wrapper/current/index.html)
3. **Control:**
   With `java.security.AuthProvider` or `iaik.pkcs.pkcs11.provider.DefaultLoginManager`, you can probably take control, if it's from the provider. 
   If it's not enough, try the wrappers or both.
4. **Code tested:**
   With `java.security.AuthProvider`, i still see the CKR_PIN_INCORRECT from the device, but now i can catch the `LoginException` from the login.

   ```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       /*
           Properties config = new Properties();
           config.put("library", "/path/someVendor_pkcs11.dll");
           config.put("name", "Token1");
       */      
       try {

           SunPKCS11 result = new SunPKCS11("res/pkcs11.cfg");
           if (result.getService("KeyStore", "PKCS11") == null) {
               throw new RuntimeException("No PKCS#11 Service available. Probably Security Token (Smartcard) not inserted");
           }

           // Register the Provider 
           if (Security.getProvider(result.getName()) != null) {
               Security.removeProvider(result.getName());
           }

           Security.addProvider(result);
           //throw new RuntimeException("Failed to install SUN PKCS#11 Provider",e);

           AuthProvider pkcs11Prov = result; 
           //Provider pkcs11Prov = result; //no possibility of explicit login
           pkcs11Prov.login(new Subject(), new SwingPasswordCallbackHandler()); //explicit login

           CallbackHandlerProtection pwCallbackProt = new CallbackHandlerProtection( new SwingPasswordCallbackHandler() );         
           KeyStore.Builder builder = KeyStore.Builder.newInstance("PKCS11", pkcs11Prov, pwCallbackProt);
           KeyStore ks = builder.getKeyStore();        

           for(Enumeration<String> aliases = ks.aliases(); aliases.hasMoreElements(); ) {
               String alias = aliases.nextElement();
               System.out.println(alias);

               // print certifcate
               Certificate cert = ks.getCertificate(alias);
               if (cert != null) {
                   System.out.print(" Certificate found. type="+cert.getType());

                   if (cert instanceof X509Certificate){
                       System.out.print(" SubjectDN="+((X509Certificate)cert).getSubjectDN());
                   }
                   System.out.println();
               }

               // private key is accessed without password 
               Key pk = ks.getKey(alias, null);
               if (pk != null) {
                   System.out.println(" Private key found. algorithm="+pk.getAlgorithm());
               }

               System.out.println();
           }

       } catch (KeyStoreException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException("Failed to load PKCS#11 Keystore",e);            
       } catch (LoginException e) {
           System.out.println("LoginException: Here, you can SWING!!!");
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (UnrecoverableKeyException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```